# search bar with debounce using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, searchbar

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function AutoCompleteInput() {

    const[data,setData] = useState([])
    const [filtereddata,setfilteredData]=useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
      const Timer = setTimeout(()=>{
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then((res)=>{
              //console.log(res.data[0])
                setData(res.data)
                setfilteredData(res.data)
            })
            .catch((err)=>console.log("some error"))

      },2000)
      
      return()=>clearTimeout(Timer)  
      
    },[data])
    

    const handleChange=(searchvalue)=>{
       // console.log(value)
      
        const filteritems= filtereddata.filter(item=>item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchvalue))
       //console.log(filteritems)
         setData(filteritems)
      
     }
  return (
    <div>
         <input type="text" placeholder="search here..." onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e.target.value)}/>
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                       <th>username</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                         <th>phone</th>
                    </tr>
                      
                </thead>
                   
                <tbody>
                {data.map((d,i)=>{
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                             <td>{i+1}</td>
                              <td>{d.name}</td>
                               <td>{d.username}</td>
                               <td>{d.email}</td>
                               <td>{d.phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                            )
                    })}
                </tbody>
                 
            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default AutoCompleteInput
```

I have queries to this:

1. In useEffect I have given the dependency array as second argument to avoid the unnecessary
   re-rendering, so do I need to pass something in it ,If I am passing "data" here in dependency
   array it will search item for sometime and again display the whole list or Do I need to pass something else in Dependency array???
2. I am using Debounce here so that for each search query it will not make the API call but it is not displaying the data related to item that I have search in search bar after 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array so the user data is fetched only once when the component mounts.
2. Since you are fetching the data only once, there is no need to use a timeout or debounce anything.
3. Don't duplicate the fetched state. Simply store the value you would like to filter by and apply an in-line filter of the `data` state.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function AutoCompleteInput() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((res) => setData(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log("some error"));
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="search here..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={searchValue}
      />
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>index</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>username</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th>phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
                   
          <tbody>
            {data
              .filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
              .map((item, index) => (
                <tr key={item.username}>
                  <td>{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.username}</td>
                  <td>{item.email}</td>
                  <td>{item.phone}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: then in what scenerio I need to use debounce? I read in many articles that we need to use it in search bar because if we don;t use it then it wil make the api call for each letter that we type in for search. Can you givesome example to explain it?

Comment: @poojathakur If you were actually making network requests in real time to fetch data based on user input, then you'd want to debounce that handler function so you aren't making unnecessary intermediate requests that are possibly invalidated by the next keystroke. See ths [answer](/a/66394949/8690857) of mine for a small  debounced fetch function example.

Comment: Here in my example I don't need to use debounce but if I want to use Is this is the correct way(syntax wise ) how we do debouncing in hooks?

Comment: @poojathakur The answer I linked to in my previous comment has an example for debouncing the function that makes the backend data fetch.